# React navigation 5 canGoBack() for stack navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

I’m using react-navigation for my app and I have a tab navigator which contains a stack navigator. I want to use `navigation.canGoBack()` for only the stack navigator. So if a user is at the top screen in the stack nav (and there's no going back in that stack) I want it to return false. The way it works now is that canGoBack is always true (unless i’m on the first tab screen when the app starts. It takes me to different tabs). Is there any solution/work-around for this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. The line below allows you to check how deep you are inside a stack. So if index is 0 that means you are on the top screen of that stack.
`const index = useNavigationState(state => state.index);`

docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state/

Comment: This seems to also have a problem where it is true, when I'm not on the screen.

Comment: Solution is shared on react-navigation v5 docs - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#no-more-isfirstrouteinparent